# How can I relatively link to a sub folder in HTML?

Tags: html

On page `/foo` I would like to link to `/foo/bar`. `<a href="./foo/bar">` works, except that it requires me to know that I'm currently on `/foo`.

Is there a way that I can just append a suffix without needing to know the current path?

Comment: You can define once in `<head><base href="./foo/bar/"></head>` and on that file you can use `<a href="somethig.jpg">`

Comment: Better to use path relative to domain, always beginning with forward slash. There is no need to use base href.

Comment: @HakikZaman How do I get the base to be the current URL though? Is there a way without using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

At "html" "head" you can define base path and all other hrefs can be relative to this base.
Some examples of "base" tag:

```
<base href="https://www.example.com/">
<base target="_blank"> 
<base target="_top" href="https://example.com/">
```

Comment: How do I get the base to be the current URL though? Is there a way without using JavaScript?